# Mixing Etiquette?

Tags: privacy

Is there a best practice or consensus for obfuscating one's own funds?

Example:

I have 10 XMR in my wallet.  If I would like privacy, is it (probabilistically) best to:

Create a new wallet and send all 10 xmr there.
Send the full 10xmr back to the same wallet (that I am currently using).
Send 5 (or some #) of xmr back to the same wallet.
etc.

Comment: Can you elaborate about the specific privacy threat scenario you're concerned about?

Comment: Determined hacker or researcher who's trying to determine the source or destination of my funds?   
Going off the deep end, though, let's pretend one large exchange has been hacked (the database of all xmr transactions are leaked).   I have done kyc etc. on a second exchange, and so the operators know me.  Too well, however,  I'm best buds with the owner but also the owner's wife and am having an affair with her.  The owner is suspicious and wants to determine who paid for her first class airfare to London last weekend (which was done via his site from a customer who had not done kyc).

Comment: There is no consensus, recommendation or best practice yet. The MRL is researching the potential of techniques such as churn. You are correct to flag your specific scenario for caution.

Answer (score 2):

There is no agreed-upon consensus for this scenario. Overall, you are describing a process known as "churning."

You do not actually need to use a separate wallet to churn. You can simply send Monero to the same address.

There is little evidence to suggest churning is *worse* than not churning. Likewise, there is some evidence to suggest that churning is more effective than not churning. However, MRL has so far been cautious in issuing any statements or recommendations.